# Сортировка многомерного массива от наибольше к наименьшему

Tags: php, сортировка

Есть много подобных массивов:

```html
Array
(
[11] => Array
    (
        [pos] => >100
        [count] => 23
    )

[40] => Array
    (
        [pos] => >100
        [count] => 125
    )

[41] => Array
    (
        [pos] => >100
        [count] => 15
    )
)
Array
(
[14] => Array
    (
        [pos] => >100
        [count] => 154
    )

[15] => Array
    (
        [pos] => >100
        [count] => 46
    )

[16] => Array
    (
        [pos] => >100
        [count] => 10
    )

)
```

мне нужно отсортировать по ключу count, чтобы шло по умеьншению и сверху всегда был тот, который больше
для каждого массива делаю так:

```html
usort($array, function($l, $r) { 
    return strcmp($l["count"], $r["count"]); 
});
print_r($array);
```

Но на выходе получаю то, где первый стоял с наибольшим значением переходит в другое место, а где не было наиболее становится первым. Как лучше сделать? ведь массивов много, а до сортировки я не знаю где первым стоит наибольший?

```html
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [pos] => >100
            [count] => 125
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [pos] => >100
            [count] => 15
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [pos] => >100
            [count] => 23
        )
)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [pos] => >100
            [count] => 10
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [pos] => >100
            [count] => 154
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [pos] => >100
            [count] => 46
        )

)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[strcmp](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strcmp.php)

> Возвращает отрицательное число, если str1 меньше, чем str2

, а вам надо просто их сравнить. Если у вас может прийти не int, то его надо привести к int.

```
usort($array, function($l, $r) { 
   return (int)$l["count"] >  (int)$r["count"]; 
});
```